# How to decide which module is a submodule of the other in git?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Assume a module `A`, and a testing module for it, `T`.
I would like to decide which of them should be the sub module of the other.

Intuitively, it would make sense to me to make `T` a sub module of `A`, because it has no meaning on its own.

However, I read for example [here](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407) that

> ... if the technological context allows for packaging and formal
> dependency management, you should absolutely go this route instead

Please assume we don't have the capacity right now to set up a packaging pipeline, thus need to use sub modules.

By that rationale, it would make sense to treat `A` as a package, and "install" it for `T`, which would mean `A` is actually a sub module of `T`.

---

This is confusing to me, and I would like to know the best practice for this use case, and preferably also thumb rules on how to decide on the main question of "what is a sub module of what".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mainly use submodules to reach a very high control over your dependencies. Considering the case of `A` and `T`, `A` should definitely be the submodule because it is a dependency of `T`. It is more likely that you want to stick with `A` as a submodule, so that your testing project `T` targets a specific version of `A`.

Moreover, it feels more natural to me if my project `A` is a submodule, so a dependency, of many other projects: in this way each of them can pull the version of `A` they are compatible with.

Last but not least, imagine that you want to restart from zero the testing project `T`: if `A` is a submodule, you can destroy `T` without worrying of anything. Instead, if `A` has `T` as a submodule, you need to take care of that and redo the linking with the new testing project.

About the thumb rule, here is MINE: if `A` depends on `B`, `B` becomes the submodule. Following this rule, the dependency can be developped separately.